# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryMessaging

Tags: swift, xcode, flurry

I recently upgrade Xcode to 14.X, and I'm getting the following error when building

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryMessaging
```

Seems like Flurry package doesn't support Xcode. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am an engineer on Flurry's SDK team. Based on your description you are using Swift Package Manager?

1. Make sure you have imported Flurry analytics and messaging: [image]
2. Add a import statement for messaging:

   import Flurry_iOS_SDK

   import Flurry_Messaging
3. Note Flurry Messaging is only supported on iOS and tvOS

---

For Cocoapods you need have the following in your Podfile:

pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'

You should see the frameworks here:

[image]

Otherwise the instructions are the same as the above.

I have sample code for Flurry Messaging implementation here:

https://github.com/flurrydev/iOS-Push-notification-sample-swift

If this doesn't clear up the issue for you reach out to me at support@flurry.com

Comment: Hi @Hunter, I'm using pods

Comment: I updated the answer above and provided a link to a sample app. Feel free to followup with me  via at support@flurry.com and I can help further.